# Spring Security : Always bad Credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use authenticate using in-memory users but i always keep getting "bad credentials" even when they are right .

**WebSecurityConfig.java:**

```
package com.skillshare.project.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test").password("{noop}test").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that in any place you don't use an password encoder?

Comment: yeah i'm not using an encoder anywhere :/

Comment: what are your spring security debug logs saying?